# Problems with ChakraUI Custom Menu Button

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

Im using ChakraUI to create a menu for my website. I want to set my custom Image Component as the MenuButton which is required for the Menu Component from ChakraUI to work properly. I tried two methods which I found on the web and these were the problems I faced:

**Method 1:** [forwardRefs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/overlay/menu#customizing-the-button)

As the website said I wrote code so that my custom component could accept the ref passed by MenuButton. Sadly the button doesnt work.

```js
const Menu = () => {
  const { user, signOut } = useAuth();

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{
        opacity: 0,
      }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.4, delay: 0.2 }}
    >
      <Menu>
        <MenuButton as={CustomButton}></MenuButton>
        <MenuList>
          <MenuItem>Test</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </Menu>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

```js
import { forwardRef } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const CustomButton= forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { user, signOut } = useAuth();

  return (
    <motion.img
      ref={ref}
      whileHover={{ scale: 1.1, rotate: "-360deg" }}
      whileTap={{
        scale: 0.95,
        borderRadius: "10rem",
      }}
      src={
        "https://source.boringavatars.com/beam/240/" + user.email + "?square"
      }
      height="50px"
      width="50px"
    />
  );
});
```

**Method 2:** [Chakra Framer Motion](https://chakra-ui.com/guides/integrations/with-framer)

Did as the website said. The Button works properly now, but once I click the button, the animation stops working indefinitely.

```js
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

const ProfileButton = () => {
  const { user, signOut } = useAuth();
  const MotionMenuButton= motion(MenuButton)

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{
        opacity: 0,
      }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.4, delay: 0.2 }}
    >
      <Menu>
        <MotionMenuButton
           whileHover={{ scale: 1.1, rotate: "-360deg" }}
           whileTap={{
             scale: 0.95
      }}>
           <Image
             src={"https://source.boringavatars.com/beam/240/" + user.email + "?square"}/>
        </MotionMenuButton>
        <MenuList>
          <MenuItem>Bonk</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </Menu>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but might help someone having the same issue.

In the method 1, make sure to spread the props object as well:

```
import { forwardRef } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const CustomButton= forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { user, signOut } = useAuth();

  return (
    <motion.img
      ref={ref}
      whileHover={{ scale: 1.1, rotate: "-360deg" }}
      whileTap={{
        scale: 0.95,
        borderRadius: "10rem",
      }}
      src={
        "https://source.boringavatars.com/beam/240/" + user.email + "?square"
      }
      height="50px"
      width="50px"
      props={...props}
    />
  );
});
```